# Preprocessor identifier in front of function declarations in a header file

Tags: c++

I was reading a header file and I noticed that the programmer has put a preprocessor identifier in front of the return values of functions in their declarations, as following.

```
#ifndef SAMPLE_API
#define SAMPLE_API
#endif

...

namespace SampleName
{
    SAMPLE_API bool api_function();
    ...
}
```

What's the purpose of it and how does it work?

**Edit**: I am reading `imgui.h` from the [IMGUI](https://github.com/ocornut/imgui) project.

Comment: It's very diffult to say specifically what the purpose is without knowing what said header belongs to. Many frameworks, e.g. Cocoa and Qt, use empty macros to "tag" things for various tools that need to read the headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By defining `SAMPLE_API` (on your compiler command line, in your Makefile / IDE environment etc.), you could add something to each function declaration in this header.

If you did **not** define `SAMPLE_API`, the first couple of lines...

```
#ifndef SAMPLE_API
#define SAMPLE_API
#endif
```

...make sure that `SAMPLE_API` is "defined away", i.e.

```
SAMPLE_API bool api_function();
```

...is preprocessed to...

```
bool api_function();
```

...so "nothing happens" (instead of "syntax error" when the compiler runs into `SAMPLE_API` and does not know what to do with it).

**The usual reason for a construct like this `SAMPLE_API` symbol is to handle symbol export / import when building / using a library for Windows.**

You would define `SAMPLE_API` to...

- `__declspec(dllexport)` when *building* a library for Windows,
- `__declspec(dllimport)` when *using* a library for Windows,

...so the symbols for the functions in question get exported / imported as necessary.

There are other things that could be done with such a preprocessor symbol (like deprecating functions, so that the linker will warn if they are being used), or other platform-specific stuff. But I would guess you're looking at dllexport / dllimport plumbing here.

Answer (score 1):

In this *particular* case it does nothing. (Remember that the *preprocessor* does little more than trivial copying and pasting).

*But*, it *might* be useful in some instances to declare for example, a `declspec` for exporting a DLL function (in which case it would be `#DEFINE`d to something less trivial. Needless to say, that kind of thing is not formally part of the C++ standard, but rather is likely exploiting compiler extensions.